# Will Ink Cartridges Bought in UK Work on a Canon Pixma Pro 100 Printer Bought in the USA?

Tags: canon, printer, ink-jet

I'm in the UK and looking to pick up a Pixma Pro 100. The cheapest prices here are around £330 ($503), but it seems there are some great deals to be had on Ebay from the USA. It appears that many people there got the printers as part of some kind of promotion and are flipping them for instant profit. These go for around £200 including delivery and customs charges. The sellers have good feedback.

A while ago I remember talking to a guy who had brought a printer over from the USA, but found none of the ink cartridges bought here worked (something to do with differences in the chip) and was forced to order inks from the USA (not sure what brand printer it was).

**So will cartridges bought in the UK work on an American Pixma Pro 100?**

Comment: I also can't answer your question, except to say that I buy cheap cartridges from meritline and they have all functioned properly - even the low-ink warning works. http://www.meritline.com/canon-pgi-225-plus-cli-226-ink-compatible-with-new-chip-combo-5---p-66377.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Seems it's true:

A definitive answer from Canon Customer Services from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/450614/how-can-i-alter-the-region-lock-on-a-canon-printer):

> Thank you for contacting Canon product support. We value you as a
>   Canon customer and appreciate the opportunity to assist you. I am
>   sorry that your PIXMA MP560 is not recognizing the CLI-221 and PGI-220
>   ink tanks you purchased.
>
> The reason that the printer is not recognizing these ink tanks is
>   because these were purchased here in the United States and your PIXMA
>   MP560 was from the United Kingdom. The ink must be purchased from the
>   Canon division where you purchased the printer. Unfortunately, this
>   means that the ink from the United States would not work in your UK
>   PIXMA MP560. It would need to come from a United Kingdom dealer.
>
> I am sorry for any inconvenience this causes. Please let us know if we
>   can be of further assistance with your PIXMA MP560.

However all is not lost. Apparently there is a cheap [hardware device](http://www.octoink.co.uk/products/Canon-CLI%252d526%7B47%7DPGI%252d525-Redsetter-%5BUSB%5D.html) available that can reset the region (its main use seems to be for resetting ink levels if you refill your cartridges manually.

Comment: +1 Good answer, but WTF? If I move countries, I need to either buy a new printer or order inks internationally! That's terrible for everyone expect the manufacturer. Greed is surely thriving! :(

Answer (score 5):

I talked to Canon rep from my country who told me that the printers remember the first ink tanks..doesnt matter if they come from USA or EU market or Asian. They all have diff numbers that are stored in the printers memory after the first use

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer your question, but I buy imported ink from China directly to the US all of the time for my Canon printer without regard for the country of origin and do not have issues.